# I am requesting the xlsb file from my sharepoint development site using rest API

Tags: excel-services

the code is as follows.,

```
    function getResponse() {
      var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
      console.log(hostweburl);
      request.set_url(hostweburl + "/sites/techvision/
      _vti_bin/ExcelREST.aspx/Shared%20Documents/Template.xlsb/
      model");
      var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);
      console.log("making the request to the sharepoint");
      context.executeQueryAsync(
      function(sender, args) {
        onGetTemplateInfo1(response);
      },
      function(sender, args) {
        onGetTemplateInfoFailure(sender,args);
      }
    );
    }
```

but it is giving me the error. "An exception occurred while processing the request… reference not set to an instance of an object.'."

Comment: Can you please tell me on which line in your code do you get the error? Can you please post the stacktrace as well?

Comment: in onGetTemplateInfo1(response); function when i print response object

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Excel Services REST API** is as simple as specifying a URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) in your web browser.  In this post weâ€™ll walk through the details of the URI syntax.

Kindly check the details for how to use REST API for excel in below URL.

[Excel Services in SharePoint 2010 REST API Syntax](https://blogs.office.com/2009/11/05/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-rest-api-syntax/)

Comment: You will get the xslb as a response as per the above link. It is byte XLS file so you will get the same result. Please put the **onGetTemplateInfo1** function in your question to understand it properly.